# I'm not able to read lines after the filter in Pandas with Selenium

Tags: python, pandas, excel, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new to Pandas and Selenium and I have a small doubt with Pandas and Selenium. I'm extracting data from an Excel spreadsheet to send to a web form as a test.

I have an Excel spreadsheet called "REL_COMUNICADO_DE_VENDA.xlsm" and my idea is to capture only the chassis numbers (Chassis No.) according to the 'Status' filter == 'Registered'.

[image]

Filter applied according to the rule 'Status' == Registered and capture the lines of the entire column 'Chassis Number'

[image]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# read excel file(NºChassi) (Column 'P')
planilha = pd.read_excel("REL_COMUNICADO_DE_VENDA.xlsm")
filtroCadastrado = planilha['Situação'] == 'Cadastrado'
planilha_filtrada =  planilha[filtroCadastrado]
**#Chasssi number filter**
planilha_filtraChassi = planilha_filtrada['Nº Chassi']

for index,row in planilha.iterrows():
    navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
    navegador.get("http://www.google.com")
    time.sleep(2)

    campoFormularioElemento = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="APjFqb"]')
    campoFormularioElemento.send_keys(row[planilha_filtraChassi])
    time.sleep(2)

    navegador.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'gNO89b').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    navegador.quit()
```

If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it.

I expected to bring lines from the column ['Chassis Number'] after filtering the 'Status' == Registered

Comment: what is your question? Is it about reading the excel with pandas and applying the filter? Is it about making the request using selenium?

Comment: It's about reading each line by line with Pandas and passing it to Selenium